# size of run in Timsort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, timsort

I am study the Timsort from this link
[hackernoon Timsort](https://hackernoon.com/timsort-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-youve-never-heard-of-36b28417f399)

There is a statement "Merging 2 arrays is more efficient when the number of runs is equal to, or slightly less than, a power of two. Timsort chooses minrun to try to ensure this efficiency, by making sure minrun is equal to or less than a power of two."

Why "Merging 2 arrays is more efficient when the number of runs is equal to, or slightly less than, a power of two"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for balanced merges in the general/random case (if the given data isn't random but has long natural runs, then `minrun` and thus the choice for it might not matter much, and the balance depends more on the lengths of the runs than on the number of runs).

In the general/random case you expect to produce runs of exactly `minrun` elements. Then when the number of runs is a power of 2, you get perfectly balanced merges throughout. If the number of runs is a bit *larger* than a power of 2, you end up with a very unbalanced merge. If the number of runs is a bit *smaller* than a power of 2, you get only a little imbalance.

Again, this is (at least mostly) for the general/random case. If you for example have *nine* natural runs of lengths 800, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 elements, then you also get perfectly balanced merges throughout, despite the number of runs being slightly *larger* than a power of 2.

Excerpt from Tim's own description in [`listsort.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3fe9117779f0c75f7a0c3d7748c5bf281fbc1e4c/Objects/listsort.txt#L267-L283) regarding this choice of `minrun`:

```
Because sortperf.py only tries powers of 2, it took a long time to notice
that 32 isn't a good choice for the general case!  Consider N=2112:

>>> divmod(2112, 32)
(66, 0)
>>>

If the data is randomly ordered, we're very likely to end up with 66 runs
each of length 32.  The first 64 of these trigger a sequence of perfectly
balanced merges (see next section), leaving runs of lengths 2048 and 64 to
merge at the end.  The adaptive gimmicks can do that with fewer than 2048+64
compares, but it's still more compares than necessary, and-- mergesort's
bugaboo relative to samplesort --a lot more data movement (O(N) copies just
to get 64 elements into place).

If we take minrun=33 in this case, then we're very likely to end up with 64
runs each of length 33, and then all merges are perfectly balanced.  Better!
```